# Used iPhone asks for iCloud credentials of the previous owner

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I have a used iPhone that asks me for the previous owner’s iCloud password. As the phone was purchased a long time ago (around 2 years) I no longer have their contact details.

My questions are:

- Is there a way I can remove the phone from their iCloud account?
- Or, if I update the phone to the latest version of iOS, will it ask me for the iCloud credentials?

I remember updating my own phone once, and I wasn’t asked for my iCloud password.

Comment: Is "Find my iPhone" activated (check in Settings)?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions to your problem is doing a full reset of this used iPhone by following these steps:

Settings->General->Reset->Erase All Content and Settings

**Note:** this will remove everything that is currently stored on your iPhone and remove any association with Apple ID as well.

After the reset, you can proceed to update your iPhone to the latest iOS available to your model.